# SQL query automation, group by with only table name changing?

Tags: sql-server-2012, automation

I have a list of tables that I want to summarize all the same way save the table names will change, can someone point me at the right tool for this job?

Example:

select strm, snapshot, count(*) from table1 where strm in ('2167','2157') group by strm, snapshot order by strm, snapshot

select strm, snapshot, count(*) from table2 where strm in ('2167','2157') group by strm, snapshot order by strm, snapshot

select strm, snapshot, count(*) from table3 where strm in ('2167','2157') group by strm, snapshot order by strm, snapshot

I get the results I want with this approach, but it seems cumbersome with 40-60 tables one by one...     I use SQL MS 2016 if this gives any help with my options.  TIA 8)

Comment: PS I am loving SQL, but am a total greenhorn.   I come from Unidata DB background, it is totally dif from SQL.  ...oops and I meant SQL SMS 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will search all tables in your catalog containing both a `strm` and `snapshot` column and build your query dynamically.

```
declare @TSQL nvarchar(max) = (select distinct 'select strm, snapshot from ['+
TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' +
TABLE_NAME + '] where strm in ('2167','2157') group by strm, snapshot order by strm, snapshot '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T0 
where exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1 where C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'strm' and T0.TABLE_SCHEMA = C1.TABLE_SCHEMA and T0.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME)
and exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2 where C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'snapshot' and T0.TABLE_SCHEMA = C2.TABLE_SCHEMA and T0.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME)
for XML PATH(''))

exec sp_EXECUTESQL  @TSQL
```

Comment: I could not quite get your code to work however just on a guess I dropped the where portion of the code and it works and hard coded dbo.   I did guess at a few other things and got it to add  the table title.   awesome   thank you.

Answer (score 0):

declare @TSQL nvarchar(max) = (select distinct 'select strm, snapshot, count(*) as ' + T0.TABLE_NAME + ' from [dbo].[' +
TABLE_NAME + '] group by strm, snapshot order by strm, snapshot '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T0 
where exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1 where C1.COLUMN_NAME = 'strm' and T0.TABLE_SCHEMA = C1.TABLE_SCHEMA and T0.TABLE_NAME = C1.TABLE_NAME)
and exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2 where C2.COLUMN_NAME = 'snapshot' and T0.TABLE_SCHEMA = C2.TABLE_SCHEMA and T0.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME)
for XML PATH(''))

exec sp_EXECUTESQL  @TSQL

--Thank you Mr Anderson that was a big help, I guess I need to work study TSQL.